# Ruby : Watir : How to avoid closing browser from Net::ReadTimeout?

Tags: ruby, while-loop, webdriver, watir

I am making an automation program using Watir , that reads links from a file `links.txt` and then open one by one on chrome browser. When it takes to much time to open then browser and its on loading time it shows me the `Net::ReadTimeout`. I have tried to rescue and and if its not rescued go to the next link from the list.

I have tried this one but when max_retries = 3 it shows again the error. I want to make browser to wait for specific amount of time and then if it is still loading close the browser and go to the next link from the list

```
   file='links.txt'
   max_retries = 3
   times_retried = 0
   n = 0

   begin
      browser = Watir::Browser.new :chrome
      Watir.default_timeout = 1000
      rescue Net::ReadTimeout 
      browser.wait
      retry
   end

 line = File.readlines(file).sample 

  while n <= 50 do
  n+=1
    begin
    browser.goto "#{line}" 
    rescue Net::ReadTimeout => error
          if times_retried < max_retries
             times_retried += 1
             puts "Failed to load page, retry #{times_retried}/#{max_retries}"
             retry
           else
             puts "Exiting script. Timeout Loading Page"
             exit(1)
           end
     end  
break if n == 50
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to increase the page load time out, it waits default time of 60 seconds but you can increase the page load timeout by the following code

```
client = Selenium::WebDriver::Remote::Http::Default.new
client.read_timeout = 120 # seconds
driver = Selenium::WebDriver.for :chrome,http_client: client
b=Watir::Browser.new driver
```

Now your code would wait for 120 seconds for any page load which has been caused by #click and also wait to load the url by goto method.

Comment: Hello, i have used this method to but some pages take to much time to load and still got the error if it is any method like wait for a specific time and then move to the next iteration as in example that i post it

Comment: This code automatically waits for page load as a result of the click. I increased the time from 60 to 120. If it is not enough,then you can still increase. You don't have to retry in your code. Once it's set, then your `b.element.click` automatically waits until next page loads.

Comment: Is there any way to make it if the page does not load for a specific time then close the browser and go to the next line like in my example

Answer (score 0):

This is an old question, but maybe that helps someone:

```ruby
client = Selenium::WebDriver::Remote::Http::Default.new
client.timeout = 600 # instead of the default 60 (seconds)
Watir::Browser.new :chrome, http_client: client
```

Comment: This is deprecated. Use client.read_timeout.